# Google CameraXBasic stopped working on android 10?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera

I used [CameraXBasic](https://github.com/android/camera-samples) in my production app for more than several months, everything was fine until 2 or 3 weeks ago takePicture function stopped returning any callback. I tried to update version and many different ways to implement CameraXBasic on my app, but it doesn't return any callback anymore. Both onError and onImageSaved are not returned.

```
imageCapture.takePicture(outputOptions, cameraExecutor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
        override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
        }
        
        override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Photo saved successfully")
        }
    })
```

Tried versions of "1.0.0-beta10", '1.0.0-beta08" and "1.0.0-alpha04"

Did any of you face this issue? Does a CameraXBasic work for you on Android 10?

Comment: For me, it works "as is" on my Nokia 8.2 with Android 10. Try to restart your device, clean rebuild the project…

Comment: @AlexCohn yes it works on many devices. Do you have opportunity to check if your implementation works on Pixel 2 API 29 emulator? Because this is the one I get no response on.

Comment: How did you configure the camera on your emulator?

Comment: @AlexCohn as Virtual Scene